# Django Forms: Display MultipleChoiceField select options below its label

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

In my `views.py` file, I have a form with the following field:

`test_type = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label="Test Type:", choices=ALL_TEST_TYPES_OPTIONS, widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size': '15'}))`

I'm rendering it in my associated `.html` template file by using `{{form.as_p}}` inside of the following `<form>` tag:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{response.status_code}} - {{response.reason}}
        {{page_errors}}
        {{form.as_p}}
```

It displays as such:

[image]

**My goal, which I'm seeking suggestions on how to achieve, is to simply put the select options below the label** ("Test Type:"), rather than the current formatting of the select options being to the right of this label.

Perhaps there's a command to perform this styling within its definition (in `views.py` as I inserted above) along the lines of what I did for setting its `size` attribute to be 15. Or, if there's a way I could break up its rendering in the HTML file to insert a `<br>` (line break) between the label and select options.